# Display a list from nested json: Sencha Touch 2

Tags: json, extjs, javascript-framework, sencha-touch-2

I have a list that displays a list of restaurants with the logo of the restaurant etc.

**The view**

```
Ext.define('Test.view.Contacts', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'contacts',

    config: {
        title: 'Stores',
        cls: 'x-contacts',

        store: 'Contacts',
        itemTpl: [
            '<div class="headshot" style="background-image:url(resources/images/logos/{logo});"></div>',
            '{name}',
            '<span>{add1}</span>'
        ].join('')
    }
});
```

When you tap the restaurant i want it to show another list based on the item tapped.

**The second view**

```
Ext.define('Test.view.Menu', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'contact-menu',

    config: {
        title: 'Menu',
        cls: 'x-contacts',

        store: 'Contacts',
        itemTpl: [
            '<div>{item}</div>'
        ].join(''),
    },
});
```

**The models**

```
Ext.define('Test.model.Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            'name',
            'logo',
            'desc',
            'telephone',
            'city',
            'add1',
            'post',
            'country',
            'latitude',
            'longitude'
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'contacts.json'
        }
    },
    hasMany: {
        model: "Test.model.Menus",
        name: 'menus'
    }
});

Ext.define('Test.model.Menus', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'item'
        ]
    },
    belongsTo: "Test.model.Contact"
});
```

**The store**

```
Ext.define('Test.store.Contacts', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

  config: {
    model: 'Test.model.Contact',
    autoLoad: true,
    //sorters: 'name',
    grouper: {
      groupFn: function(record) {
        return record.get('name')[0];
      }
    },
    proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: 'contacts.json',
      reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'stores'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**The JSON**

```
{
    "stores": [{
        "name": "Science Gallery",
        "logo": "sciencegallery.jpg",
        "desc": "Get some food",
        "telephone": "016261234",
        "city": "Dublin",
        "add1": "Pearse Street",
        "post": "2",
        "country": "Ireland",
        "latitude": "53.34422",
        "longitude": "-6.25006",
        "menu": [{
            "item": "SC Sandwich"
        }, {
            "item": "SC Toasted Sandwich"
        }, {
            "item": "SC Panini"
        }, {
            "item": "SC Ciabatta"
        }, {
            "item": "SC Burrito"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Spar",
        "logo": "spar.jpg",
        "desc": "Get some food",
        "telephone": "016261234",
        "city": "Dublin",
        "add1": "Mayor Street",
        "post": "2",
        "country": "Ireland",
        "latitude": "53.34422",
        "longitude": "-6.25006",
        "menu": [{
            "item": "Spar Sandwich"
        }, {
            "item": "Spar Toasted Sandwich"
        }, {
            "item": "Spar Panini"
        }, {
            "item": "Spar Ciabatta"
        }, {
            "item": "Spar Burrito"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to show a list of menu items (item, item, item...) for the restaurant selectedbut when I use a nested list I have to use the same template as the previous list which doesnt suit my needs. At the moment I get the right amount of items but nothing shows. Can you please help me with where I'm going wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before I get to the solution, here are a few problems with your code (which need to be fixed before the solution will work):

- In your proxy config within the `Contacts` store, the config for the roog of your JSON is `rootProperty`, not `root`.

  ```
  proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: 'contacts.json',
      reader : {
          type : 'json',
          rootProperty : 'stores'
      }
  }
  ```

  You could also just put this code inside your model, as you already put a proxy config in there. Here are both merged (should be inside your model, and remove proxy from the store):

  ```
  proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: 'contacts.json',
      reader : {
          type : 'json',
          rootProperty : 'stores'
      }
  }
  ```
- Model names should always be singular as they represent one object. So use `Menu`, not `Menus`.
- You need to require any classes you use inside the class you use them. For example, you need the `Sencha.model.Menu` class inside the `Sencha.model.Contact` class, so add it inside the `requires` property inside `Contact.js`:

  ```
  Ext.define('Sencha.model.Contact', {
      extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
      requires: ['Sencha.model.Menu'],

      ...
  });
  ```
- You need to use `associationKey` in your hasMany association as normally it would look for `menus` (generated from the Model name), but in your JSON is it `menu`.
- `hasMany` and `belongsTo` configs should be inside `config` block within your models.

  ```
  Ext.define('Sencha.model.Contact', {
      extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
      requires: ['Sencha.model.Menu'],

      config: {
          ...

          hasMany: {
              model: "Sencha.model.Menu",
              associationKey: 'menu'
          }
      }
  });
  ```

As for the **solution** :) - you can modify your `itemTpl` inside your list to display associated for the record being shown. To do this, you can use:

```
<tpl for="associatedModelName">
     {field_of_associated_model}
</tpl>
```

So in your case, you can do something like this:

```
itemTpl: [
    '{name}',
    '<div>',
        '<h2><b>Menu</b></h2>',
        '<tpl for="menus">',
            '<div> - {item}</div>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</div>'
].join('')
```

Here is a download of a project (generated using the SDK Tools) which includes a demo of this, using mostly your code: http://rwd.me/FS57

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rdougan, Going to try it and i'll confirm your answer.

Comment: Sorry @rdougan i tried the example you provided, i've gotten that far but now i want to display the list of restaurants first and then when you tap one of them it will show another list of just the menu items, can you help me with achieving this.

Comment: Got it sorted, used a nested list with tpl for the different nodes.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. So, if you wanted to do that, I'd recommend you just use a NavigationView and then push separate Ext.List views into it. Using a NestedList does not make sense in that situation. :)

Comment: I actually found a way of of styling a nested list but thanks anyway.

Comment: @rdougan thanks for a very good explanation, can you also give a sample/link which uses navigation view and seperate Ext.List views please.

Comment: Also,the project that you have provided, is it suppose to show menu items in another list, because when i select a store.. nothing happens :(