# Sencha touch 2, printing nested JSON array using xtemplate

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am developing a simple movie listing app.
I am using rotten tomatoes api. following is the json :

```
movies": [{
                "id": "771310572",
                "title": "Cloud Atlas",
                "year": 2012,
                "mpaa_rating": "R",
                "runtime": 163,
                "release_dates": {
                        "theater": "2012-10-26"
                },
                "ratings": {
                        "critics_rating": "Fresh",
                        "critics_score": 80,
                        "audience_score": 98
                },
                "synopsis": "Cloud Atlas explores how the actions and consequences of individual lives impact one another throughout the past, the present and the future. Action, mystery and romance weave dramatically through the story as one soul is shaped from a killer into a hero and a single act of kindness ripples across centuries to inspire a revolution in the distant future. Each member of the ensemble appears in multiple roles as the stories move through time. -- (C) Warner Bros.",
                "posters": {
                        "thumbnail": "http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/16/71/11167192_mob.jpg",
                        "profile": "http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/16/71/11167192_pro.jpg",
                        "detailed": "http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/16/71/11167192_det.jpg",
                        "original": "http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/16/71/11167192_ori.jpg"
                },
                "abridged_cast": [{
                        "name": "Tom Hanks",
                        "id": "162655641",
                        "characters": ["Dermot 'Duster' Hoggins", "Dr. Henry Goose", "Isaac Sachs", "Valleysman Zachry"]
                }, {
                        "name": "Halle Berry",
                        "id": "162652386",
                        "characters": ["Jocasta Ayrs", "Luisa Rey", "Meronym"]
                }, {
                        "name": "Jim Broadbent",
                        "id": "162653369",
                        "characters": ["Vyvyan Ayrs"]
                }, {
                        "name": "Hugo Weaving",
                        "id": "162709905",
                        "characters": ["Bill Smoke", "Nurse Noakes", "Old Georgie"]
                }, {
                        "name": "Jim Sturgess",
                        "id": "563717190",
                        "characters": ["Adam Ewing", "Hae-Joo Im"]
                }]
```

I am able to get the first list view showing the list of movies and ontap on movie list item, I am able to load the next view to show the movie details.

I am stuck in displaying abridged_cast in the xtemplate. if I use {abridged_cast} the page displays object, Object.

I am unable to find any functions which will extract the values from this array and display.
How to display the array content in the template?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicated: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949229/display-a-list-from-nested-json-sencha-touch-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949229/display-a-list-from-nested-json-sencha-touch-2)

Comment: Thank you, it works.
I tried this before, but didnt work for me at that time. As i didn't understand the concept of displaying associated records in template
<tpl for="associatedModelName">
     {field_of_associated_model}
</tpl> .

Comment: Oops! For me only first array item is being displayed :(. The example posted in the URL also has the same issue.

Comment: @timbaktoo You might want to update your question then, and explain in detail what is not working. Otherwise, this is basically a duplicate of that (and very well may be even if edited)

Comment: I got it working. I used loop in the template 

 <tpl for="abridged_cast">
 <li><b>{name}</b><br/>Characters: [ {characters} ]</li>
 </tpl>

Comment: This was suggested in the the duplicate link. I understood the concept. But I didn't use the hasMany and accociationKey method suggested there as it was retuning a recursive object with only first item of the array.